# printing a shape with numeric

Tags: c++, shapes

```
int number1=5;
int number2=4;
for(int i=1; i<=7; i++)
{
    if(rows <= 1)
        for(int i=1; i<=7; i++) 
        {
            cout<< number1;
        }
    else if(i<7)
    {
        cout<< endl;
        for(int j=1; j<=6; j++) 
        {
            if(side2==1 || side2==6)
                cout<< number1;
            else
                cout<< " ";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout<< endl;
        for(int k=1; k<=6; k++)
        {
            cout<<number1;
        }
    }
```

My program prints this shape

```
 555555555
 5       5
 5       5
 5       5
 5       5
 555555555
```

but I have been trying to make it look like this

```
 555555555
 544444445
 543333345
 543222345
 543212345
 543222345
 543333345
 544444445
 555555555
```

I have heard about this website from a friend how much helpful you guys are, I wish you would help me too.

Comment: Are you sure you've got your language tag right?  How are you getting `cout <<` to do anything in Java?

Comment: I did not do that someone changed the tag, I tagged c++ shapes

Comment: You can see some related examples [here](http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/pyramid-pattern).

Comment: Actually you tagged "shape" and "box". "c++" is a much more useful tag :)

Comment: Please format the code to make it readable

Comment: anyone plz? i need it asap

Comment: Hint: the number is relative to distance from center...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be:

```
std::cout << "555555555" << std::endl;
std::cout << "544444445" << std::endl;
std::cout << "543333345" << std::endl;
std::cout << "543222345" << std::endl;
std::cout << "543212345" << std::endl;
std::cout << "543222345" << std::endl;
std::cout << "543333345" << std::endl;
std::cout << "544444445" << std::endl;
std::cout << "555555555" << std::endl;
```

and with a loop:

```
for (int y = 0; y < 9; ++y) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 9; ++x) {
        std::cout << char('1' + std::max(std::abs(x - 4), std::abs(y - 4)));
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```